# Looking for a distribution to describe 2D "lines"

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a 2D surface endowed with line segments, i.e. the function contains sparsely distributed segments in which there is high correlation between adjacent points in some direction, and the rest of the function is zero.

I'm looking for a vector distribution that describes such a function. Does this ring a bell?

For example, a realization of a random matrix with this distribution should look like so.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but "high correlation between adjacent points in some direction" has little meaning. You'd better show a picture I guess.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: You could try some marked point process

Comment: I don't see any correlation of any kind.

Comment: Please describe symbolically  using mathematical symbols what you mean by "*high correlation between adjacent points in some direction*". I get a sense like $ x_{i} $ = $ x _{i+1}$, but am not too sure.